# Volume formed by rotation the curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, rotations

Find the volume formed by rotating the curve:

$y(x)=e^{-x}\sqrt{\sin x}, x>0, \sin x\ge0$

around the $x$-axis

Hint: $2n\pi\le x\le(2n+1)\pi$ for $n=0,1,2,3...$ as $\sin x \ge 0$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I got no idea what to do

Comment: I have tried to do $V=\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} e^{-2x}sinx dx$ and I have obtained $\frac{\pi}{5}\frac{exp(-2\pi)+1}{1-exp(-4\pi)}$. Can you confirm the result or the method?